# bigquery.Client().extract_table() does not (always) divide a big table into small CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-python

My Python application needs to export BigQuery tables into small CSV files in GCS (like smaller than 1GB).

I referred to the [document](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.extract_table), and wrote the following code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigquery.Client().extract_table('my_project.my_dataset.my_5GB_table',
                                destination_uris='gs://my-bucket/*.csv')
```

The size of `my_5GB_table` is approximately 5GB.
But it results in a single 10GB CSV file in GCS.[image: GCS image]

I tried with other tables with various numbers of size, and then some resulted in divided files of about 200MB, and others in a single huge file too.

The [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data?hl=en) says as if tables are always divided into 1GB files, but now I don't know the rules where the files are divided.

**Q1** How to make sure that tables are always divided into smaller than 1GB files ?

**Q2** Can't I specify the size of files into which tables are divided ?

Comment: For Q2: there's a [BigQuery feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123603261) may be related. It is asking for extracting part of table. You may watch on the request to get announcement when it is supported.

Comment: @YunZhang Thank you, this would be definitely what I need.

Comment: So the answers of Q1 and Q2 are "I cannot." ? :(

Comment: That's really odd. BigQuery shards any tables > 1GB to multiple files. I've never seen it export a single file that size before. Maybe a Googler can chime in here to explain that one. My best guess is that they are making some changes for Next in a few weeks behind the scenes :) You can *not* specify the size of the files. It will vary with each export.

Comment: My own experience is that if I try to export a table greater than about 1GB without a wildcard specified in the filename, it fails with an error indicating that it needs to shard the results... you are supplying a wildcard and the result size ought to be sharded on that basis.